# Rails - execute an ajax call via select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a view that contains a `select` tag, it is not part of a form just a stand alone drop down menu. On clicking one of the options I want to execute an ajax call

This is the select tag

```
<%= select_tag 'application_stage', options_for_select(application.job.hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }), prompt: "Hiring stage", class: 'input-block-level chzn-select hiring_stage_dropdown', id: 'hiring_stage_dropdown' %>
```

and this is a basic jquery through which I am trying to detect the change

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        console.log('clicked');
        $("#hiring_stage_dropdown").click(function() {
            var state = $('select#hiring_stage_dropdown :selected').val();
            console.log(state);
        });
    })
```

But when i select one of the options nothing happens, I know the ajax code is not there but all i want for now is to see something in console when one of the options is selected.

What am i missing here?

This is what the select looks like

```
<select class="input-block-level chzn-select hiring_stage_dropdown" id="hiring_stage_dropdown" name="application_stage">
  <option value="">Hiring stage</option>
  <option value="3">Manager Step 1</option>
  <option value="4">Manager Step 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Executing an AJAX call when selecting an item from a select dropdown is built in to Rails via jquery-ujs.

First, make sure you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile and `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application.js manifest file (they are both there by default).

Then add `data-remote`, `data-url`, and `data-method` attributes to your select. jquery-url will serialise the value of the select and make the request. Your `select_tag` code might look like:

```
<%= select_tag(
  'application_stage',
  options_for_select(
    application.job.hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  ),
  prompt: "Hiring stage",
  class: 'input-block-level chzn-select hiring_stage_dropdown',
  id: 'hiring_stage_dropdown',
  data: {
    remote: true,
    url: '/your_path',
    method: 'get'
  }
) %>
```

When a value is selected, jquery-ujs will make a `GET` request to `/your_path?application_stage=:selected_value`. You can then handle this in a js.erb response.

Comment: Nice, suppose I want to make a post request only and do not want anything in return, I know can change the method to post but how do i pass the value of selected option in this post request? will the rails automatically send the selected value in params?

Comment: Yes, change the `method` to `post`, and the selected value will appear in `params[:application_stage]` in your controller action

Comment: Thanks alot, this is much better than trying to do ajax on my own. what a relief.

Comment: The above code does the ajax call only when I select a selection. But what to do if I wanted to make a default call when the page is rendered? @DomChristie

Comment: @NaveenHonestRajK Just incorporate your function into `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { });` if you are using turbolinks or just go with on-load.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code this will work : Use `change` event instead of `click`

```js
//jQuery(function($) {
        $("#hiring_stage_dropdown").on("change",function() {
            var state = $(this).val();
            alert(state);
        });
//    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="hiring_stage_dropdown">
<option value="-1">Select Any Option </option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes seems to be working here and stand alone but not when i integrate this in rails

Comment: can you try removing `jQuery(function($) {` from function

Comment: Yes i tried this as well and still does not work and yes i tried .click and .change both

Comment: This is correct actually. @Saadia one of the options of your select has a null value. Try selecting any other option which has a value and check.

Comment: Thanks Pavan and Pankan I will go with Dom answer as that seems pretty straight forward. I appreciate you taking out time to help.