# Rails 6 ActiveAdmin dynamic dropdown selection with page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6, formtastic

I have a following ActiveAdmin form

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :dropdown_a, # Dropdown menu
      f.input :dropdown_b, # Dropdown menu
      f.input :quantity
      f.input :remarks
    end
  end
```

I want to dynamically select options of `dropdown_b` depending on value of `dropdown_a`. How can I achieve this? It doesn't have to be javascript. I am fine with reloading page with selected values onchange.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could extract something from this question:
[Rails - pass a parameter to controller from form select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958281/rails-pass-a-parameter-to-controller-from-form-select-dropdown)

Using as collection for the second dropdown a variable, nil at the start, and once the user change the first dropdown an ajax request is made and the variable receive the new value from params.